# How to connect vertices without creating faces?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, faces, topology

[image]

Here, I have two square grids without any face, and I wanna connect the vertices between the two grids without creating any face.

**Method I**:

Step 1: Select all grids, then "*Edge*" -> "*Bridge Edge Loops*". But this way not only connects vertices but also creates unwanted faces. (as the screenshot below)

[image]

Step 2: To remove all the faces without removing the connections, I can press <kbd>x</kbd>, then "Delete" -> "Only Faces".
[image]

Yeah, this method works, but it requires two steps. Is it possible to do it in one step please? This means to only connect vertices without creating any face.

(By the way, the **Method II** would be to select each pair of vertices and press <kbd>f</kbd>, but it requires four steps, much more tedious.)

Comment: If you want to do it in one step (i.e., all vertices are selected at once), how exactly should Blender know in which direction it should connect them? It looks obvious on a mesh like that, but suppose this would be a function for all meshes?

Comment: Blender knows it, because its built-in function "Edge" --> "Bridge Edge Loops" knows the direction of the connect. But the trouble is that it creates unnecessary faces.

Comment: Because that's the only direction how you can produce planar, non-concave, manifold faces (except for deliberately twisting them with the tool settings). Straight edges without any problematic geometry can be produced in multiple directions. Maybe "shortest distance" might be a criterion, but even that is not necessarily correct depending on the geometry. Let's face it: _Bridge Edge Loops_ would be the correct tool, if you had the option to disable faces. But that's not what the tool is made for and it seems there is no built-in tool that does it.

Comment: "No built-in tool that does it." Maybe this is a good answer to this question. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know from 11 years of using Blender, but I still learn something new from time to time and features change. Maybe someone else knows better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> >  *Extrude Vertices*, with snap and automerge?

[image]

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB-Click</kbd> also gets you the vertex extrusion, but requires a <kbd>G</kbd> to locate.)